# Writing into a file, strange behavior with expansion

Tags: expansion, expl3, write

I want to write some data into a file, but I need to replace a subtring in these data beforehand. For some reason, the expansion through the `\write` macro does not give the expected result. Instead, a space is added between the control sequence doing the replacement and its argument and the evaluation is stopped. Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{expl3}

\newwrite\file

\immediate\openout\file=foo.txt

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nfn }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
 {
   \tl_set:Nn \l__maxdd_argument_tl { #1 }

  \tl_replace_all:Nfn \l__maxdd_argument_tl { \c_colon_str } { }
  \tl_use:N \l__maxdd_argument_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__maxdd_argument_tl%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\immediate\write\file{\myreplace{bar:bar}}
\immediate\closeout\file

\end{document}
```

I was expecting to see `barbar`  instead of `\myreplace {bar:bar}`

Comment: The macro `\myreplace` is `\protected`, so it doesn't expand in a `\write`. On the other hand replacements like that cannot be performed in a `\write`.

Comment: Can I get around this issue? I have a string which contains colons and I don't want to print these colons.

Comment: You could do ``{\catcode`\:=9 \immediate\write\file{bar:bar}}``.

Comment: @Saroupille My impression is that this is an XY-question. Can you please be more specific about what you need, with some more real context?

Comment: The destination file would be a dot file for graphviz. In this file, I need to give a name to some nodes. However, the name of these nodes contains colons and apparently this is not allowed. In my case, the tool `dot2tex` from this generated dot file prints incorrect LaTeX code. Hence, two options: either I change all the identifiers containing colons in the LaTeX file, either I remove the colons when I print the dot file. The second option seems more reasonnable to me.

Comment: Actually your solution does not work either @UlrikeFischer. The code printed is "{\catcode `\mskip \medmuskip =9 \immediate \write \file {bar:bar}}"

Comment: @Saroupille worked fine for me, I tested it. Setting the catcode of : to 9 lets tex ignore it completly.

Comment: My bad, catcode is outside the write function.

Answer (score 1):

`\write` works by pure expansion and your `\myreplace` command is not expandable (and cannot be). You need to do the replacement before passing the token list to the writing stage.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{expl3} % already loaded by xparse

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\writefile}{smm}
 {% #1 = * if replacement is needed
  % #2 = file name
  % #3 = text to write
  \tl_set:Nn \l__saroupille_writefile_tl { #3 }
  \IfBooleanT{#1}
   {
    \tl_replace_all:NVn \l__saroupille_writefile_tl \c_colon_str { }
   }
  \saroupille_writefile:nV { #2 } \l__saroupille_writefile_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NVn }

\iow_new:N \g__saroupille_writefile_iow
\tl_new:N \l__saroupille_writefile_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \saroupille_writefile:nn
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \g__saroupille_writefile_iow { #1 }
  \iow_now:Nn \g__saroupille_writefile_iow { #2 }
  \iow_close:N \g__saroupille_writefile_iow
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \saroupille_writefile:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\writefile{\jobname-colon.txt}{bar:bar}
\writefile*{\jobname-nocolon.txt}{bar:bar}

\input{\jobname-colon.txt}

\input{\jobname-nocolon.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`expl3` regular expressions would work but are vastly more complicated than you need here, you can simply use a `:` delimited macro to remove :.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\file

\immediate\openout\file=foo.txt

\def\myreplace#1{\xmyrepl#1\xxmyrepl:}
\def\xmyrepl#1:{#1\xmyrepl}
\def\xxmyrepl#1{}

\begin{document}

\immediate\write\file{\myreplace{bar:bar}}
\immediate\closeout\file

\end{document}
```